# Why $\int_{0}^{1} \frac{x^n}{x + 10}$ can be approximated with this unstable algorithm?

Tags: calculus, numerical-methods

We want to evaluate the integral

$$y_n = \int_{0}^{1} \frac{x^n}{x + 10}dx$$

and we develop an approximation recursive algorithm, which is based on the fact

(1)
$$y_n + 10y_{n-1} = \int_{0}^{1} \frac{x^n + 10x^{n-1}}{x + 10} dx = \int_{0}^{1} x^{n-1}dx = \frac{1}{n}$$

The algorithm is:

- Base case

$$y_0 = \int_{0}^{1} \frac{x^0}{x + 10} dx = \int_{0}^{1} \frac{1}{x + 10} dx =  ln(11) - ln(10)$$

- Recursive step

$$y_n = \frac{1}{n} - 10y_{n-1}$$

Could someone explain me the equivalence of the expressions in (1)?

From my understanding the formula in the recursive step comes from the result in (1), that is in (1) it's concluded that $y_n + 10y_{n-1} = \frac{1}{n}$, so...

*Note that I'm not asking why this approximation algorithm is unstable, but that will probably be another question.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are asking about where does (1) comes from, observe that: $$y_n+10y_{n-1}=\int_0^1\frac{x^n}{x+10}{\rm d}x +\int_0^1\frac{10x^{n-1}}{x+10}{\rm d}x$$

$$y_n+10y_{n-1}=\int_0^1\frac{x^{n-1}(x+10)}{x+10}{\rm d}x$$

$$y_n+10y_{n-1}=\frac{x^n}n |_0^1$$

$$y_n+10y_{n-1}=\frac 1n$$

If you are asking the exact formula for $y_n$ in terms of $n$:

$$y_n=\frac 1n - 10y_{n-1}$$

$$y_n=\frac 1n - \frac {10}{n-1} + \frac{100}{n-2} -...+(-1)^{n-1}10^{n-1}+(-1)^n*10^ny_0$$

$$y_n=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{(-10)^{n-k}}k + 10^n y_0$$

Comment: Typo in the last formula: Should be $ + (-10)^n y_0$ instead of $+10^n y_0$.

Comment: @Nuncameesquecideti This can be solved without knowing the formula given here. Do you know the inequality $\int_a^b f(x){\rm d}x \leq \max_{x\in[a,b]} f(x)\cdot (b-a)$? If not make a drawing to convince yourself (the integral of $f$ has to be contained in a rectangle of size $M \times(b-a)$ where $M$ is the max-value of $f$). This can be used to explain why $y_n < 1$.